# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Open Data's [first moderator election](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: albert]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Jeanne Holm who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this is a [*pro tempore* election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections), there was no need for it to be competitive. With only one nomination, we skipped the vote.

Comment: Welcome, Albert!